# Package neutralinojs without bundling

Tags: node.js, neutralinojs

Is it possible to package Neutralinojs application to production without bundling?

To make it clear, I'd like to expose the resource folder on production to make the application edit-able even on production.

I'd like to include some code, but in actuality I haven't tried anything, or wasn't able to because the documentation on Neutralinojs website is not complete yet at the moment.